# How would structures be built differently in a world populated by diminutive humanoids?

Tags: physics, construction

If I have a world where all races are one-foot-tall versions of their typical fantasy counterparts, what would be the most obvious ways this would affect the building style of these cultures? Would they be able to still build large stone structures? Would they be able to get away building more permanently out of dirt and grass?

Comment: Their buildings would be smaller.

Answer (score 3):

As these things usually go, it depends.  If there were a scaled-down version of *all* life on this planet, aside from other influential factors, everything should be as it is here, just simply smaller.  In other words, would they build the great pyramids?  Would they build the great wall?  Possibly, though it would be proportionate to their stature more than likely.  Granted, it would still be impressive by our standards, just not *as* impressive.  It is speculated that the ancient Egyptians severed the rock from the rock face by letting water enter the cracks and freeze.  This implies that it isn't a question of strength, but perhaps rather of persistence.

However, if they were one feet tall and they had larger predators, I would imagine that most of their culture would be focused on building protective structures.  They could be very intelligent, but no intelligence is going to save you when confronted against a 10-foot tall sabertooth tiger.  So it naturally follows that while we have no natural predators, they still would and so their focus behind structures would be largely protective, even if also impressive or decorative.  Imagine something like a gigantic ant hill in Africa, except with columns and arches.  It would not likely be difficult to spot a habitat for this species if you came across it in the wild, unless there were other sentient species that were smart enough to know how to attack one.

In this case, it would likely also heavily influence how they behave, focusing more on survival rather than artistic endeavours.  Our ancestors didn't start making cave drawings for artistical value but rather spiritual value.  Likely a sentient species focused on survival would build decorative structures for religious value.  Assuming they were very advanced, they would still likely be very religious in contrast to our species in which religion counts perhaps a little less.  Likely you would have seen more than one war between members of this species on account of differences of religion.

However returning to the your question, I think it is perfectly possible that you could still see structures made of dirt and grass.  Mankind has also made homes in hillsides as it was cold in the summer and warm(er) in winter.  They aren't practical however, since it wasn't uncommon to have a stray snake wander into your humble abode, I'd imagine a dirt home would be impractical for a species capable of doing more assuming they were advanced enough technologically, though perhaps their ancestors did so.

It is also likely that their homes are underground, since it is an efficient way to hide from predators without having to extend an above-ground structure to accomodate a growing population.  You'd likely still see an above ground structure that protects the entrance, but most of the "city" would be underground in contrast.  That isn't to say the walls would be made in dirt.  Conceivably they could use rock walls and floors.  The royal or noble members of the city, assuming they lived in a caste system, would likely have gold-plated floors or ceilings, while the poorer among them would have only the dirt walls, since that is all they could afford.  I assume there would be a caste system, because any sentient species with a minimal sense of self-preservation would also be somewhat selfish and greedy, and a caste system is a natural following of that.

A sufficiently advanced civilization of this culture would likely have an underground tunnel system connecting cities.  You would likely also see many of the larger predators slowly dwindle to extinction, as technology would improve to the point of global dominance.  However, I don't think you'd see a movement to the surface, since old habits die hard in any culture, and this species would likely continue to live underground.  Most above-ground structures would hold religious significance, likely in reference to the stars, as did our ancestors, since there would be no need otherwise for above-ground structures as they become an advanced civilization.  These religious structures would be impressive, even to us.  It would have their history and beliefs written in stone on it, and should we ever have the pleasure of visiting their planet, it would truly be something remarkable, even after their civilization is long gone.

In short, there would be many similarities with our own culture, except the emphasis would be heavily bent on survival, and as such, also their religions would be about survival as well.

Answer (score 3):

### Building Materials

Most buildings materials could be substituted by smaller parts of the same thing:

- Instead of felling trees they will fell twigs of branches that have fallen to the ground or maybe even climb trees to saw off smaller branches
- Stonemasons will make ashlar rocks from smaller rocks or what we think of as pebble stones.
- Bricks can be made of smaller portions of clay.
- For glass windows they will need finest SiO2
- They could also mine ore and create steel although I guess this will be harder for them
- Concrete is a realistic option as well – maybe reinforced with plant fibers

All in all modern buildings could **look the same** and use the **same materials**.

### Location

Weather conditions could severely impact where to build.

- Rain – could flood whole “valleys” – i.e. depressions or pits – so it is likely they will build on top of “mountains” – i.e. bumps or small hills – providing sufficient drainage.
- Hail – maybe they will not build structures to be hail-proof and just live with the chance of their houses being smashed just as we sometimes build wooden structures in the Tornado Alley. But they could also build their structures in natural caves or build massive stone structures that will survive big hailstones
- Lightning – this could be no problem at all with many much bigger natural structures deflecting the danger
- Wind – have you ever seen a grass root upheaved due to excessive wind? Being one foot tall will leave you with greatly reduced air resistance so this might not be troublesome as well.

I agree with @Neil that underground structures could be very common and would protect people from weather conditions efficiently. You only have to make sure the entrance can be sealed during rain fall.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the numbers to back this up, but I'd think they could build buildings relatively taller, and at earlier technological levels. A two-story building for us would be like a twelve-story building for them, and their building would have more horizontal supports. I'm pretty sure [the square-cube law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-cube_law) will back me up on this: the smaller things get, the stronger they get, relatively speaking. That's why you can build a house of normal-sized cards, but not one large enough to live in. That also means that your one-foot-tall people might be quite a bit (relatively) stronger than us, able to build much (relatively) bigger, heavier structures with less effort (as Neil mentioned, the strength of the builders isn't everything, but it helps in low-tech settings where brawn is more prevalent than brains).

This may lead to smaller, more compact cities, as wood and stone skyscrapers might actually hold up. Generally, everything will be relatively bigger for these people. To us, it would still look small, but if you ever got shrunk down to their size you'd be absolutely blown away by it.

Comment: Good point.  It would seem more impressive to you than to them, because you aren't used to things built at that scale and because you were shrunk down to that size.

Comment: This is one of the things I was wondering about the most when I posted the question. Thanks for the link to the square-cube law!

Comment: Yep, beat me too it.  Square-cube law is going to be your friend here.

Comment: @DanSmolinske That may be the first time SCL has actually helped someone around here...